# Node redirects after AJAX call to the route instead of just returning the data

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to make an AJAX request to one of my routes which should return some data, but I can't solve the fact that when I make an AJAX request I'm being redirected to the route I'm requesting.

How can I prevent this from happening?

The route I'm requesting:

```
app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    request.post({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate',
        form: {
            email: req.body.email,
            hashed_password: req.body.password
        },
    }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
        console.log(req.xhr);
        console.log(req.headers);
        if (err) {
            return console.error('failed:', err);
        }
        console.log('successful! ', JSON.parse(body));
        //user.token = data.token;
        res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    });
});
```

My AJAX request:

```
    var request    = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url        = 'http://localhost:3000/signin';

    var credentials = {
        email: document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value,
        password: document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value
    };

    JSON.stringify(credentials);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if(request.status == 200) {
                if(request.readyState == 4) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            } else if(request.status == 400) {
                console.log('There was an error 400');
            } else {
                console.log('something else other than 200 was returned');
            }
        }
    }

    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send(credentials);
```

Comment: Check `if (err) { return console.error('failed:', err); }` it's not ending/finishing incoming request, try `return res.status(400).send(err);`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I doesn't enter that if so I guess that's not where the problem lies.

Comment: Maybe out of scope, but `res.json(JSON.parse(body))` is redundant. `res.json(body)`

Comment: I parse the data because it's the backend that doesn't seem to return the response. I can't see the `console.log` that I do in the frontend, only the one that is done in the backend. Do you see anything else that's wrong?